# Can we make a tutorial page for app's fresh installment with ionic framework?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, splash-screen

I've been trying to make tutorial page for my app first installment using ionic framework. Is that even possible to make the tutorial page ? Because I can manage to make the splash screen and icon already. An Example maybe ?

Comment: What's so special about a tutorial page that it would be more difficult than other features of your app, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by storing something into `localstorage`, where on your index.html's controller, you will check for the localstorage if the user has seen the intro or not. And once the Intro page is loaded, the localstorage variable would be stored as *seen by user* or something.

I used Ionic's **[Slidebox](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSlideBox/)** example, I simply added these to the 2 controllers to check if Intro was seen.

**YourMainController**:

```
 if (window.localStorage.getItem("didIntro") === null) {
    $state.go('intro');
 }
```

**YourIntroController**:

```
window.localStorage.setItem("didIntro", "seen");
```

You can checkout [this Codepen](http://codepen.io/keval5531/pen/KwYJzv) that I modified for this.

PS: The intro would be shown to the user if they un-install the app or **Clear Data** of the app. If that bothers you, you could keep server side identification of a user and upon authentication, you could check the didIntro flag you save on your server.